# Parse Server on Openstack with docker and communicate through network with Parse API(also sign in to view parse dashboard)

Tags: docker, networking, parse-platform, dns, openstack

I'm setting up a cloud infrastructure for our institution so that students can use it for free with parse as BaaS(Backend as a Service), We want to have a dashboard where students can login and create or manage the parse instances, also the app credentials should be auto created like in back4app and also how to forwarded API request to the specific parse instance from network. Help us?

thank you for your support!!!!

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use kubernetes or sth similar to manage parse server containers. Or if your baas solution is very simple you can create your own custom baas solution of course (like with docker-compose management).

here is a link for you on medium: [Deploy and run parse-server on Google Container Engine with kubernetes](https://medium.com/google-cloud/from-zero-to-hero-run-parse-server-on-google-cloud-platform-part-2-deploy-and-run-parse-server-86e5d93296a3)